# Django - how to control and filter related objects

Tags: django, django-select-related, django-related-manager

I have two models

**Note :** there are some code i have removed to make the question simple

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    category_name           = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Courses(models.Model):
    course_name             = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
```

if i have for example 3 categories (PHP, Python, Javascript) and each one of this categories have a courses related to it like this

```
PHP = php_course1, php_course2, php_course3

Python = python_course1, python_course2, python_course3

Javascript = javascript_course1, javascript_course2, javascript_course3
```

So what i want when someone click on any category it will take him to another page which have only courses related to this category.

This what i have done to make this happen

views.py

```
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
   model               = Categories
   template_name       = 'category_list.html'
   context_object_name = 'category_list'

class CategoriesDetailView(DetailView):
   model               = Categories
   template_name       = 'category_detail.html'
   context_object_name = 'category_detail'
```

first template 'category_list.html'

```
{% for category in category_list %}

  <a href="{% url 'category' category.slug %}" class="btn">{{ category.category_name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

second template 'category_detail.html'

```
{% for course in category_detail.courses_set.all  %}

  <h1> {{ course.course_name }} </h1>

{% ednfor %}
```

this is work very well if i click on 'javascript category' for example it will show only 'javascript courses'.

**The problem** is i want to filter the courses but because i use related object like this make me don't have a context on the view so i can play with

so either the way i did is wrong that's why it's limit me and there is another good way which i want you to tell me about it or it is a good way and there is some thing that i can do to filter and play with 'courses' objects

I searched and found this but this give me all 'courses' not only the one that related to a particular 'Category'

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoriesDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['course'] = Courses.objects.all().select_related("category")
    return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter) the `Courses` model to get courses as per your category.

You have to use a similar query in your view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoriesDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['course'] = Courses.objects.filter() # Your filter query here
    return context
```

Now your filter query can be based on the `kwargs` you're capturing the `url`.

If you're capturing a slug, your filter query will be:

```
slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
# assuming that you've a field called slug in Category model
Courses.objects.filter(category__slug=slug)
```

Comment: thanks for your replay .. i tried this but doesn't give me any output or error when i use context 'course' in my template

Comment: Can you print the slug you're getting from kwargs?

Comment: this is the slug on the model class ..
`slug                    = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.category_name)
        return super(Categories, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

and this is my urls.py 
`path('tutorials/<slug:slug>/', views.CategoriesDetailView.as_view(), name='category'),`

Comment: And what is the slug that you get in `kwargs` in your view? Can you please print that?

Comment: sorry i'm very newbie :D , i don't know how to get slug from kwargs

Comment: No problem, just edit your views function `get_context_data`, type `print(kwargs)` in a line, run that code and paste the output here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196684/discussion-between-mehak-and-damar225).